# OnFocusChangeListener on an array of EditText

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext

I have an `Array` of dynamically created `EditText` in `Java` and I have a problem to set focus correctly on them. 
How do I manage the `OnFocusChangeListener` on an `array` of `EditText`?

Comment: Did you tried any code? If yes then post it here. then we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `onFocusChange()`, add this `mEditText.requestFocus()` where **mEditText** would be the the one to which you want to set the **current focus**.

Also, you can assign and retrieve ids of the EditTexts in your array by `setId()` and `getId()`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Set the Id for `EditText` dynamicaly using  `editText.setId(id);`, then implement  `View.OnFocusChangeListener` in your activity.  Finally, inside `onFocusChange` method

```
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    /* get currently focuse changed view id using v.getId() then you can 
     * build logic using that id and your EditText id
     */
}
```